# What are the files boot_app0.bin and bootloader_dio_80m.bin for? (ESP32 - Arduino IDE)

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, esp32, firmware, arduino-esp32

The ESP32 flash command, as executed by the Arduino IDE, seems to flash two bootloader files: `boot_app0.bin` at offset `0xe000` and `bootloader_dio_80m.bin` at offset `0x1000`. I wonder what these two bootloader files actually do, and why there are two of them. Below I give some more information.

### 1. Context

I'm part of a team developing a new, free IDE for microcontrollers: Embeetle IDE. We're planning to support the ESP32 microcontroller family in the near future. Therefore, I'm now studying the ESP32 build system - both the `ESP-IDF` tool and the Arduino IDE approach to ESP32 projects.

### 2. Arduino IDE flash procedure for ESP32 projects

After building the `.elf` file, the Arduino IDE launches a command to convert it into a binary:

```sh
python esptool.py --chip esp32 elf2image
                  --flash_mode dio
                  --flash_freq 80m
                  --flash_size 4MB
                  -o /tmp/arduino_build_852524/WiFiScan.ino.bin
                  /tmp/arduino_build_852524/WiFiScan.ino.elf
```

Finally, this `WiFiScan.ino.bin` file is flashed to the board, alongside two bootloader files and the partitions table:

```sh
python esptool.py --chip esp32
                  --port /dev/ttyUSB0
                  --baud 921600
                  --before default_reset
                  --after hard_reset write_flash
                  -z
                  --flash_mode dio
                  --flash_freq 80m
                  --flash_size detect
                  0xe000  ~/.arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/1.0.6/tools/partitions/boot_app0.bin
                  0x1000  ~/.arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/1.0.6/tools/sdk/bin/bootloader_dio_80m.bin
                  0x10000 /tmp/arduino_build_852524/WiFiScan.ino.bin
                  0x8000  /tmp/arduino_build_852524/WiFiScan.ino.partitions.bin
```

The default partitions table, as used by Arduino IDE, looks like this (in csv format):

```
# Name,   Type, SubType, Offset,  Size, Flags
nvs,      data, nvs,     0x9000,  0x5000,
otadata,  data, ota,     0xe000,  0x2000,
app0,     app,  ota_0,   0x10000, 0x140000,
app1,     app,  ota_1,   0x150000,0x140000,
spiffs,   data, spiffs,  0x290000,0x170000,
```

The binary equivalent of this csv-file gets flashed to address `0x8000`. There are also two bootloader files being flashed to addresses `0xe000` and `0x1000` respectively (see next paragraph).

### 3. Bootloader files

The two bootloader files being flashed are:

```
# flashed at 0xe000
~/.arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/1.0.6/tools/partitions/boot_app0.bin
```

and:

```
# flashed at 0x1000
~/.arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/1.0.6/tools/sdk/bin/bootloader_dio_80m.bin
```

> Question 1: What do these two bootloader files do?

It's also interesting to observe their locations. The first one, `boot_app0.bin` is located in a folder named `'partitions'`. It sits there alongside several partition `.csv` files. Why? But maybe that gets clear when Question 1 is answered.

The other one, `bootloader_dio_80m.bin` is located in a folder named `'sdk/bin/'` and sits alongside other files that all start their name with the `'bootloader_'` prefix:

[image]

> Question 2: As for the bootloader file flashed at address `0x1000`, I think the `'_40m'` and `'_80m'` suffixes stand for the flash speed in MHz. But I've no idea what the `'_dio'`, `'_dout'` and `'_qout'` suffixes stand for.

Please enlighten me ^_^

---

### Answer

Thanks to @Juraj, I now get a better insight into the startup procedure of an ESP32 chip. I believe it looks like this:

1. **FIRST STAGE BOOTLOADER**:
   The hardwired **ROM-bootloader** runs first. This first stage bootloader is outside the Flash memory and cannot be programmed. It loads the second stage bootloader (see next step).
2. **SECOND STAGE BOOTLOADER**:
   The first stage ROM-bootloader loads the second stage **ESP-IDF Software bootloader** at address `0x1000` in Flash. The code here is the `bootloader_dio_80m.bin` executable, which can be found in the `components/bootloader` directory of the ESP-IDF framework.
   This second stage bootloader reads the partition table found by default at offset `0x8000`. If OTA app partitions are found in the partition table, the bootloader consults the `ota_data` partition to determine which one should be booted.
3. **BOOT SWITCH**
   The **`ota_data`** section can be considered as merely a switch, located at `0xe000` in Flash. It determines if either `app0` or `app1` should boot. The switch itself is the `boot_app0.bin` binary. As Juraj says, the 2kB size is also used to take notes during OTA flashing.
4. **APPLICATION**
   The application at `app0` or `app1` executes.

Thank you also for pointing me at these resources:

- [ESP32 bootloader](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/bootloader.html)
- [ESP32 startup procedure](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/startup.html)

Comment: what is app0 & app1, can you have 2 firmware and switch at runtime

Answer (score 3):

The binary at 0x1000 is the bootloader. Arduino ESP32 has bootloader binaries corresponding to boards options in Tools menu in Arduino IDE (built from boards.txt).

The bootloader functions are documented [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/bootloader.html).

> The ESP-IDF Software Bootloader performs the following functions:
>
> - Minimal initial configuration of internal modules;
> - Initialize Flash Encryption and/or Secure features, if configured;
> - Select the application partition to boot, based on the partition table and ota_data (if any);
> - Load this image to RAM (IRAM & DRAM) and transfer management to it.

The boot_app0.bin is the OTA data partition initial content. It is documented [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/ota.html#ota-data-partition).

> The OTA data partition is two flash sectors (0x2000 bytes) in size, to prevent problems if there is a power failure while it is being written. Sectors are independently erased and written with matching data, and if they disagree a counter field is used to determine which sector was written more recently.

DIO, QIO, DOUT, QOUT are SPI modes for the flash memory. Different esp32 modules have different flash memory chips and their connection. (D is double, Q is quad)

Comment: Thank you @Juraj. So the binary at `0x1000` is the actual bootloader. While running, it has to select the application partition to boot (see point three). Making this selection is based on the partition table itself, and on `ota_data`. So the binary at `0xe000` is that `ota_data`, right? However, I'm still struggling a bit on understanding what this `ota_data` actually is/does.

Comment: the esp has a ROM bootloader to startup. from the perspective of the ROM bootloader is the 'bootloader' at 0x1000 the 'application'

Comment: as described in the doc, ota data defines which copy of the application to start. there are two partitions for the application, for two copies of the application, which switch after OTA upload. ota data is about this switching done safely

Comment: Thank you @Juraj. It's first time I hear about that **ROM-bootloader** (I'm new to ESP). At what address is it located? Is it hardwired (cannot be programmed)? About the **`ota_data`**, I now understand (thanks to your replies) that it acts a a switch, to decide if `app0` or `app1` should be booted. However, a switch should be just one byte, or perhaps a couple of bytes. It's weird that this `ota_data` is `0x2000` bytes. Why?

Comment: see the quote in the answer for the explanation of the 2 kB. the bootloader is not in flash memory, it is in ROM. it can't be replaced.

Comment: Thank you @Juraj. So the **`ota_data`** (address `0xe000`, file `boot_app0.bin`) is 2kB just for power-failure-protection reasons, right? This despite the fact that it's merely a switch, pointing to either `app0` or `app1`. Being just a switch/pointer, it's probably just one or two useful bytes, right?

Comment: they have some algorithm which uses the 2 kB to make notes while OTA flashing

Comment: Thank you @Juraj. I just updated my initial question, noting down how I interpreted all of this.

Comment: interesting is that Adafruit created an esp32 bootloader for their boards https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/variants/adafruit_feather_esp32s2 I think is is an uf2 bootloader https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-express-designed-for-circuit-python-circuitpython/uf2-bootloader-details

Comment: Is there a way to load 2 firmware and change the execution to boot_app1.bin